# Raspberry Pi 4: Sensor connection over I2C crashes Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, i2c, raspberry-pi4, imu

I have to use an IMU-Sensor for my Uni final project.

I started out with an Raspberry Pi 3B+ 1GB and an MPU-9250. The gyroscope and the accelerometer were having problems, randomly dropping the I2C connection, but the magnetometer part of the MPU was fine. I happened to have another gyroscope/accelerometer sensor on hand, so i used both of them together and all was good.

Now im using a BNO055 and a Raspberry Pi 4 4GB, because the old sensor combination had too much error in it's values.
And the same original problem occured.

Sometimes the sensors stops generating values, but the sensor is still connected when i run `sudo i2cdetect -y 1`. The script keeps running. Also as soon as i use sudo `i2cdetect -y 1` the sensor stops giving values, but was running fine before the command. A restart of the script usually fixes this.

Other times the sensor looses the I2C connection, the script throws an exception and `i2cdetect -y 1` returns nothing. I have to redo the wiring between the sensor and the pi to fix this, and even then it's not a 100% fix. The sensor usually is found with i2cdetect but the script still throws Remote I/O errors.

And now connecting the sensor at all crashes the pi, the moment the last wire is connected.

The wires are not long, just a few centimeters, and the sensor is the only thing connected to the pi.

This is the first time i'm using a raspberry pi and such sensors. If there is anything i can add that would help, like settings, then of course i will add those.

EDIT: Now the sensor is shorting somewhere and starts smoking when power is connected. I will return this one and order a new one, hoping this resolves the issues.

Comment: ...and double check all your connections as well!

Comment: The short happened after i wired it up to use UART, like shown on this image:

https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/90659

Then it also happened after i tried the previous wiring.

Comment: Linux kernel has an IIO driver for this sensor. Why don't you use it?